# Mat-select in mat-pagination is behaving abnormally

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have made a project where an user needs to perform CRUD operation & see the output in a table. Everything is working fine here but sometimes the `mat-select` in the `mat-paginator` starts behaving abnormally. I have made multiple projects but never ever saw this type of issue. Please see this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4cn3.jpg) for reference (focus on the red squared area).

I have checked my other projects to match the Angular material & Angular version but found everything is same.

What am expecting is this should not happen. Also on a side note, this is not occuring for all tables in the project in same time.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code.

Answer (score 1):

After some deep level debugging & looking at the CSS files of each component, I notice that I wrote the below CSS for the dialog that's opening in the video. Removing that fixed the issue.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```